# Images on s3 require a page refresh to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Carrierwave to upload images to s3 on a free Heroku dyno (although this happens locally as well). The page where I display the image has them loading as a CSS background image (inline CSS styles).

My issue is that the images doesn't load until I refresh the page. And then if I visit another image in the same Model, it loads what seems to be the previously cached image.

Here's the associated code:

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**image_controller.rb**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  # using a different layout for the show action
  layout :resolve_layout

  def show      
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])

    # set variables for image width and height
    img = Magick::Image::read(@image.image_url.to_s).first
    @width = img.columns
    @height = img.rows
  end

  private
    def resolve_layout
      case action_name
      when 'show'
        'image'
      else
        'application'
      end
    end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div style="background: url('<%= @image.image_url.to_s %>');"></div>
```

Chrome's network monitor shows nothing loading the first time I click through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running javascript on that image / element. I had exactly same issue once and turned out that there's a script manipulating the element. Hope that helps.